# How do you prevent a user from editing values in javascript

Tags: javascript, editing

Say I have a JavaScript game and i want to upload the persons high score to my database to have a leaderbord or highscores. How would you prevent a user from cheating and manually changing the score value in JavaScript before I save the score in the database?

Comment: If you only want to use JS, you can try obfuscating/encrypting the score (instead of leaving it plain text), as you cannot prevent a user from editing JS values.

Comment: @Scorpion if the encryption is done on the client side there is nothing to stop the user using your own JS code to encrypt their fake score and submit it

Comment: That one went by me, but then again I think he just wants basic level 'security'

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is executed in a user's browser, therefore there is no way to prevent the user from tampering with your code. Use a server-side programming language to manage the score.

Comment: That depends on what kind of game you have created and might require significant rework of your game. If its only a small project I'd recommend obfuscating and minifying your code, like Scorpion suggested.

Answer (score 2):

One way I would do it is to send all user actions to your server, in real time or within the final value. This way you can compute the score based on that server side and validate it. I'm assuming you've got a way to simulate a game based on the actions log.

Comment: is actions log the users input eg moves

Comment: I know nothing about your game, but moves could be the unit. Think of it like a multiplayer game where someone else could see any player evoluting in their environment.